# Polly.Extensions.Http not accessible for IHttpClientFactory - .Net6

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-6.0, polly

I need to use **Polly.Extensions.Http** for same reason.

I install Polly and Polly.Extensions.Http packages, and have these using's

```
global using Polly;
global using Polly.Retry;
global using Polly.Timeout;
global using Polly.Extensions.Http;
```

but when need add to HttpClient, It's not available!

[image]

> **[I use these refrence](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly.Extensions.Http#using-pollyextensionshttp-with-ihttpclientfactory)**

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory

Comment: For future, please check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.pollyhttpclientbuilderextensions.addpolicyhandler?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) first. It tells you where the functionality reside (in which assembly).

Comment: @JHBonarius The documentation clearly states: `Assembly:
Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly.dll`

Comment: The `Polly.Extensions.Http` package is deprecated. It has not been modified more than 3 years.

Comment: Trying the guide on a Net6 proyect tho: Microsoft.Extensions.Http.***ERROR***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

- Like Peter Csala said: *"The `Polly.Extensions.Http` package is deprecated. It has not been modified more than 3 years."*
- The new way to use `Polly` with the `HttpClientFactory` is described in [the wiki of the `Polly` github](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory). It seems to use `Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly`.

E.g.

```cs
services.AddHttpClient("GitHub", client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.github.com/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.github.v3+json");
})
.AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy(builder => builder.WaitAndRetryAsync(new[]
{
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
}));
```

Comment: Funny enough: "The Polly.Extensions.Http package is deprecated", but Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly uses Polly.Extensions.Http

Comment: @zameb could only be for backwards compatibility or such. I don't know 